# Highcharts with new data from jSON is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I have implemented Highcharts successfully which is working very good. My highcharts are getting live data at every 1 minute and add points which is doing as expected. But I have certain problem likes 
My highcharts is having two series First is line type series and second is area type series. First series will get always 2 points only and second will get more than 200 points. As I told you my data is live, data start coming on 7 AM just for line  and blank data for area until 9 AM  at exact 9 AM new data will start coming at every 1 minute until 12.30 PM but what happens at 9 AM my chart goes stop and even on new next day 7 AM my chart stop

But if i refresh my browser I get new data and it will start working as we needed.

My code as follows

```
$(function () {
   $('#container').highcharts({
       credits: {
           enabled: 0
       },
       title: {
           text: null
       },    
       xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime',
           dateTimeLabelFormats: {
               minute: '%H:%M'
           },
           max: <%= MilliTimeStamp(_closingTime) %> ,
           min: <%= MilliTimeStamp(_openingTime) %> ,
           tickInterval: 0.5 * 3600 * 1000,
           minorTickInterval: 0.1 * 3600 * 1000,
           title: {
               text: null
           },
           lineWidth: 1,
           minorGridLineWidth: 1,
           endOnTick: true,
           showLastLabel: true,
           gridLineWidth: 1,
           labels: {
               style: {
                   font: '7.5pt Trebuchet MS'
               }
           },
           reversed: <%= isArabic %> // true for arabic layout and false for english layout
       },
       yAxis: {
           title: {
               text: null
           },
           max: <%= maxY %> ,
           min: <%= minY %> ,
           endOnTick: true,
           showLastLabel: true,
           labels: {
               style: {
                   font: '7.5pt Trebuchet MS'
               }
           },
           opposite: <%= isArabic %> // true for arabic layout and false for english layout
       },
       legend: {
           enabled: false
       },
       plotOptions: {
           area: {
               fillColor: {
                   linearGradient: {
                       x1: 0,
                       y1: 0,
                       x2: 0,
                       y2: 1
                   },
                   stops: [
                       [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                       [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                   ]
               },
               lineWidth: 1,
               marker: {
                   enabled: false
               },
               shadow: false,
               states: {
                   hover: {
                       lineWidth: 1
                   }
               },
               threshold: null
           },
           line: {
               lineWidth: 1,
               marker: {
                   enabled: false
               },
               shadow: false,
               states: {
                   hover: {
                       lineWidth: 1
                   }
               },
               threshold: null
           }
       },
       tooltip: {
           formatter: function () {
               return '<span style="font-size:7.5pt;">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %e %B, %H:%M', this.points[0].x) + '</span><br><span style="color:' + this.points[0].series.color + ';">' + this.points[0].series.name + '</span>: <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.points[0].y, 0) + '</b>';
           },
           useHTML: true,
           shared: true
       },
       series: [{
           type: 'area',
           data: []
       }, {
           type: 'line',
           color: 'Red',
           data: []
       }]
   });

   <%
   if (isArabic == "true") { %> Highcharts.setOptions({
           lang: {
               months: <%= months %> ,
               weekdays: <%= days %>
           }
       }); <%
   } %>

   $.ajaxSetup({
       cache: false
   });
   recieveData();
});

function recieveData() {
   var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
   var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
   $.ajax({
       url: '/' + pathArray[1] + '/HomePageChartData.aspx',
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       data: {
           'time': new Date().getSeconds()
       },
       success: function (data) {
           chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(data.minY, data.maxY, true, true);
           chart.series[1].setData([]);
           chart.series[1].name = data.lineSeriesName;

           chart.series[0].setData([]);
           chart.series[0].name = data.areaSeriesName;

           for (var x in data.lineSeriesData) {
               chart.series[1].addPoint([data.lineSeriesData[x][0], data.lineSeriesData[x][1]]);
           }

           for (var x in data.areaSeriesData) {
               chart.series[0].addPoint([data.areaSeriesData[x][0], data.areaSeriesData[x][1]]);
           }
           setTimeout(recieveData, 60000);
       }
   }
   });
}
```

my JSON data at 7 AM

```
   {"maxX":"1367843400000","minX":"1367830800000","maxY":"7912","minY":"7511","tickIntervalY":"80","lineSeriesName":"Open","areaSeriesName":"Price Index","lineSeriesData":[[1367830800000,7715.35],[1367843400000,7715.35]],"areaSeriesData":[]}
```

my JSON data after 9 AM

```
  {"maxX":"1367843400000","minX":"1367830800000","maxY":"7912","minY":"7511","tickIntervalY":"80","lineSeriesName":"Open","areaSeriesName":"Price Index","lineSeriesData":[[1367830800000,7715.35],[1367843400000,7715.35]],"areaSeriesData":[[1367830831000,7740.01],[1367830897000,7735.61]]}
```

And it will start getting new data in areaSeriesData every 1 minutes

@@Update

I found the problem that at 7 AM and 9 AM I was not getting data I was getting empty string, so it was going to error which I was not handling, now I change it as below which start removing series but now I am not getting series for line at 7 AM which have data.Can somebody tells me what I am missing or doing wrong over here.

```
    function recieveData() {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + pathArray[1] + '/_layouts/KSE.SharePoint/HomePageChartData.aspx',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data:{'time': new Date().getSeconds() },
            success: function (data) {
              chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(data.minY, data.maxY, true, true);
              chart.series[1].setData([]);
              chart.series[1].name = data.lineSeriesName;

              chart.series[0].setData([]);
              chart.series[0].name = data.areaSeriesName;

              for (var x in data.lineSeriesData) {
                chart.series[1].addPoint([data.lineSeriesData[x][0], data.lineSeriesData[x][1]]);
              }

              for (var x in data.areaSeriesData) {
                chart.series[0].addPoint([data.areaSeriesData[x][0], data.areaSeriesData[x][1]]);
              }
              setTimeout(recieveData, 60000);
            },
            error: function() {
              setTimeout(recieveData, 60000);  
            }
          });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your json to prepare separate data for series. Morever you need to use data, instead of "lineSeriesData" or "areaSeriesData". So it should looks like:

[{
  data:[[1367830800000, 7715.35],
                    [1367843400000, 7715.35]] 
},{
  data:[[1367830831000, 7740.01],
                    [1367830897000, 7735.61]]
}]

Comment: Thanks for reply but than how can I distinguish which one is for line series and which One is for area series

Comment: You can use loop which will check if it is area (i.e by name or index of array) and push object into correct serie.

Comment: So I do in this way is correct way `{"maxX":"1368025200000","minX":"1368003600000","maxY":"7239","minY":"7086","tickIntervalY":"31","lineSeriesName":"Open","areaSeriesName":"Price Index","data":[[1368003600000,7151.89],[1368025200000,7151.89]],"data":[[1368004289000,7150.9],[1368004355000,7147.44],[1368004421000,7147.44],[1368004487000,7147.44],[1368004553000,7149.58]]}`

Comment: So it works properly, or did you come across any problems with this json ?

Comment: no i did not try. I just wanted to ask you that is it ok and if you don't mind can you send me code for parsing data please :)